# Are event binding, property binding, and two-way data binding concerned with the DOM or template?

Tags: html, angular, data-binding, components

In the Angular docs, an image shows the data flow from component to the template in property binding, and from the template to the component in event binding. However, shouldn't is be the DOM, not the template?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. Angular uses the Component you define coupled together with your template in order to build an HTML view to insert into the DOM. When any of your component `@Input` properties change then Angular knows where those inputs lay inside the DOM view in order to change them. The same goes for event callbacks. All the component callback functions (which can be custom `@output` emitters or native HTML element event emitters like `onclick`) that you define in your template are created by Angular and attached to the actual HTML elements. They go through the template and not the DOM because it needs to be able to handle both the `@Output` emitters and native event emitters.

This section will describe it as well https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components#data-binding.

Comment: I still do not understand why the picture shows that the flow is from the template to the component instead of from the DOM to the component

Comment: Update the answer a bit. Essentially, Angular has to handle the inputs and outputs (custom emitters, DOM events) of the component to DOM relationship for a consistant change detection functionality. You can't have the DOM talking to the component because it has no idea what a custom component is or what data binding is either.

Comment: Ok so what I understand is that because the DOM does not have direct contact with the component, everything has to be done through the template; therefore, it was safe to say that data flows from template to component in event binding, or data is in sync between the template and the component in two-way data binding, right?

Comment: Yes. At a high level I think it's safe to say that's what happens.